# Twitter and Facebook won't appear on UIActivityViewController Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, facebook, twitter

I'm trying to give the user an option to share the contents of the selected tableview row via Twitter or Facebook. I've tried the following

- Importing the Social Framework
- Testing on a real device
- Logging in on my personal Twitter on the simulator
- Creating' addTwitter' and passing it through the activityItems array.

[image]

```
    let shareAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Share") { (action: UITableViewRowAction, IndexPath) -> Void in

        let addTwitter = [UIActivityType.postToTwitter]


        let firstActivityItem = self.startups[indexPath.row]


        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [firstActivityItem,addTwitter], applicationActivities: nil)

        self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }
```

Does anybody have the solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `activityItems` parameter should contain the things you want to share.  If it's a string or URL, the system should figure out which share extensions and action extensions apply based on the context.  You can get more customized.

Essentially all share targets will be enabled unless you explicitly exclude it. That means you don't need to pass in `UIActivityType.postToTwitter` at all.

Just pass an array of things to share (like a `String` and `URL`) and Twitter should be able to figure out what you mean and the icon will be shown.